# Using enumerate to iterate over a CGPoint array to create multiple sprites

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to loop over a positions array to create a bunch of spriteNodes. However I'm getting the error **Value of type '[CGPoint]' has no member 'enumerate'**, for the second line. What am I doing wrong?

```
func createEnemy1() {
    let positions = [CGPoint(x: 50, y: 30), CGPoint(x: 30, y: 20)]
    positions.enumerate().forEach { (index, point) in
      let spriteNode = SKNode()
      spriteNode.position = point
      let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemy")
      sprite.zPosition = 3.0
      sprite.name = "enemy\(index + 1)"
      spriteNode.addChild(sprite)

    }
}
```

Comment: `enumerated()`?

Comment: @KentaroOkuda thats worked, thank you. I was following someone else's 4 year old code. Had never used enumerated before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this syntaxis too:

```
func createEnemy1() {
    let positions = [CGPoint(x: 50, y: 30), CGPoint(x: 30, y: 20)]
    for (index, point) in positions.enumerated() {
        let spriteNode = SKNode()
        spriteNode.position = point
        let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemy")
        sprite.zPosition = 3.0
        sprite.name = "enemy\(index + 1)"
        spriteNode.addChild(sprite)
    }
}
```

or

```
func createEnemy2() {
    let positions = [CGPoint(x: 50, y: 30), CGPoint(x: 30, y: 20)]
    positions.enumerated().forEach{ index, point in
        createAt(point: point, index: index)
    }
}

func createAt(point: CGPoint, index: Int) {
    let spriteNode = SKNode()
    spriteNode.position = point
    let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemy")
    sprite.zPosition = 3.0
    sprite.name = "enemy\(index + 1)"
    spriteNode.addChild(sprite)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the API is misspelled.

Apart from that you are mixing up tow different forms

It's either `forEach`

```
positions.forEach { (index, point) in
   let spriteNode = SKNode()
   spriteNode.position = point
   let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemy")
   sprite.zPosition = 3.0
   sprite.name = "enemy\(index + 1)"
   spriteNode.addChild(sprite)
}
```

**or** a `for` loop with `enumerated()`

```
for (index, point) in positions.enumerated() {
   let spriteNode = SKNode()
   spriteNode.position = point
   let sprite = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "enemy")
   sprite.zPosition = 3.0
   sprite.name = "enemy\(index + 1)"
   spriteNode.addChild(sprite)
}
```

but never both.